# Store and Load File from URL

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata, nsurl, writetofile

**iPhone App**

I am currently trying to understand how i can store a file from a URL to the documents directory and then read the file from the documents directory..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some.website.com/file"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Timetable.ics"];

[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

I got this code from http://swatiardeshna.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-save-file-to-iphone-documents.html

I want to know if this is the **correct** way to do this and i want to know how i can **load** the file from the documents directory into an NSString..

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks correct, to read that file back into a string use:

EDIT: (changed usedEncoding to encoding)

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:storePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Of course you should change the string encoding type if you are using a specific encoding type, but UTF8 is likely correct.

Comment: Firstly thank you for the reply.. i been going around in circles lol
But now it just crashes.. with no information showing on the console.. on xcode its highlighted your 2nd line with this in yellow:
    Passing argument 2 of 'stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:' makes pointer from integer without cast.

Comment: I am so new at it that i didnt even figure it out lol
But thank you for that!! Its doing exactly what its supposed to :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this on your main thread, then no it's not correct.  Any sort of network connection should be done in the background so you don't lock up the interface.  For that, you can create a new thread (`NSThread`, `performSelectorInBackground:`, `NSOperation`+`NSOperationQueue`) or schedule it on the run loop (`NSURLConnection`).

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but how would i do it?